# Creating a rust macro that generates traits based on data

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a generic class of API clients.  The data returned can be generically handled, but there's quite a bit of boiler plate to do so.  So I'm trying to write a macro that does something like this:

Where it transforms:

```
gen_code! {
   People,
   updated_trades = Vec<Trades>,
   new_quote = Quote,
}
```

```
trait APITrait {
  fn updated_trades(&self) -> Vec<Trades>;
  fn new_quote(&self) -> Vec<Trades>;
}


impl APITrait for Client {
  fn updated_trades(&self) -> Vec<Trades> {
     self.client.get("updated_trades").into()
  }

  fn new_quote(&self) -> Vec<Trades> {
     self.client.get("new_quote").into()
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's a typo here that `new_quote` returns `Vec<Trades>` instead of `Quote`? Where does `People` factor in?

Comment: What technical problem are you having at this point?

Comment: What is your question then? You don't know how to to such transformation? If you provide more details of what code exactly should be generated and what are your inputs we could help you write it. But now it's to vague.

Comment: > You don't know how to to such transformation?

Yes, I did not know how.  There aren't exactly that many examples in the rust book, and implementations in existing libraries tend to be too complex for a beginner to understand.  Quite a bit of a trial and error is needed to get good at Rust macros.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
// Try to choose descriptive name as with anything
macro_rules! impl_api_definitions {
    // The outer repetition allows you to define the traits in bulk
    ($(
        // lets make the macro bit more fluent and easier to read, also notice that
        // I format the macro pattern as the input should be formatted
        $vis:vis impl $name:ident for $target:ty {$(
            // lest choose syntax close to rust
            fn $method:ident -> $return_type:ty;
        )*}
        
        // notice that `$` signifies macro specific syntax:
        // - `$()` is a capture group that should be followed by
        //   - `*` zero or more repetitions of the group
        //   - `+` one or more repetitions of the group
        //   - `?` zero or one repetitions of the group
        // - `$name:type` binds a syntax of `type` to a `$name` variable;
        // each use of the variable will expand to captured code
    )*) => {$(
        // just to showcase, you can also make visibility of the trait configurable
        $vis trait $name {$(
            fn $method(&self) -> $return_type;
        )*}

        impl $name for $target {$(
            fn $method(&self) -> $return_type {
                // i removed into, it does not really make sense, rather make the get deserialize
                // into return value, note though that that can fail and so you might need to
                // handle error
                self.client.get(stringify!($method))
            }
        )*}
    )*};
}

// little mock-up of your setup
struct Client;
pub struct Trade;
pub struct Quote;
impl Client {
    fn get<T>(&self, _: &str) -> T {
        todo!()
    }
}
struct ClientWrapper {
    client: Client,
}

// example use
impl_api_definitions! {
    pub impl Api for ClientWrapper {
        fn updated_trades -> Vec<Trade>;
        fn new_quotes -> Quote;
    }

    impl PrivateApi for ClientWrapper {
        fn updated_trades -> Vec<Trade>;
        fn new_quotes -> Quote;
    }
}
```